# Koala breaks page when compile

Tags: sass, koala

I downloaded a project that it's written (the styles) on .scss and now I want to add some styling. I downloaded Koala so I can compile the .scss file with the css file but when I open Koala and then I click 'compile' without even adding more styling, it breaks the whole page (menaing that the styles become really weird). It never gives me an error not on the site, not on koala.

This is how my koala looks like
[image: This is how my koala looks like]

Is this a normal behavior or does anyone has a solution maybe?

Comment: What exactly does it do to your styles?

Comment: The pictures get bigger, the font changes and the style too, it just ruins all the design